# stack overflow error when i open Delphi XE IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

When i open Delphi XE get this message and i must close IDE.

message :

> Danger: stack overflow - save your work and restart Delphi XE

I uninstall Delphi and cpp XE and reinstall them, but already get this message.

Why?

Comment: Check this link http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=80222 is for Delphi 2010, but maybe helps you.

Comment: +1 for asking a "stack overflow" question on stackoverflow.com. ;-)

Comment: StackOverflow errors on StackOverflow are a recursive call who in turn can provoke a StackOverflow... not sure if it occurs at the browser (client) or at the server side of the application. +1 for that!. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why i revived this error message.
but i make a new user-account in windows and run Delphi XE from it, don't receive any err.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: That is not a real answer here is the real answer  https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=46103

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an error somewhere in a package.

What 3rd party components or own packages did you recently install?

When you re-install Delphi under a new user, you get a fresh new set of Delphi registry keys, and the default package load list and order.

When you re-install Delphi under an existing user, you keep the existing registry keys, and therefore the package load list and order that fails.

Compare these lists, then disable (package by package) the ones not in the new user until Delphi loads fine.

Then start adding packages (skipping the one that failed) to see if there might be more than one package causing a failure.

The root registry key where Delphi XE keeps the settings is this one:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\
```

The same trick works for other Delphi versions.

[Rodrigo Ruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz) made a [list of these keys for up to Delphi XE](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/detecting-installed-delphi-versions/).
[Modelmaker Tools](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer) made a [more complete list that includes Delphi XE3 as well](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/faq/mmx-install.html).

Answer (score 2):

stack overflow error when i open Delphi XE IDE :

This type of errors raises because of the third party component installation, you just do the following things,

1. uninstall thirparty component (if exists)
2. reset the internet explorer settings (because of that only you will get stack overflow error while opening welcome page in delphi IDE)
3. now restart your Delphi IDE

for further details visit http://nanosofttechno.blogspot.in/2013/08/stack-overflow-save-your-work-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue for Embarcadero, contact their support/QA with your license number.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem has appeared in my machine at the same time in D2007, D2009, D2010 and DXE.

It seems to be something similar to this report at embarcadero:
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=80222

If I rename the 'Welcomepage' as suggested in the link above, the IDEs open (with a blanc page and a message).
Here, I can create a new simple project but the IDE takes the 100% CPU when I try to write some code and I have to kill it through Task Manager.
This happens in the mentioned IDEs once renamed the 'Welcomepage' and also happens in D2005 and D2006, where I don't get the 'stack overflow' error at the IDE startup.

Deleting the registry keys suggested in the article above seems to do nothing for me.
The error happened before and after installing Update 1 for XE.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling XE to eliminate 3rd party packages possible problems.
I've tried cleaning all the browsers cache as suggested too.

Recent changes: Some drivers for a Sony Ericson mobile, some Windows XP updates. Not much more.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score -1):

Having the same problem with D2010/WinXP, the solution that helped was:

Open IE explorer (or Maxthon in my case), open Settings panel, select Clear history and delete all items (browser history, address line history,cache,....)

It looks like start of newer Delphi version depends on successfull opening of the IE explorer engine with Welcome page and if it fails from some reason, Delphi freezes.